# Make composer.lock of global php for heroku

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I am using *heroku* to deploy a `python` app that calls a `php` script, in local it is working great, but when I deploy to heroku I get a *SoapClient error*, my guess is that the version and the extensions in my local machine are not the same as the ones that are installing in heroku.

Is there a way to make a composer.json or composer.lock of the same version and extensions in my local machine to deploy in heroku?

Edit:

I am getting this SoapClient error:

```
SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://200.23.37.80:3737/appr_tc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://200.23.37.80:3737/appr_tc?wsdl"
```

And this is my composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
       "ext-soap": "*",
       "ext-openssl": "*",
       "php": "^5.5.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: It will help in answering if you add to your question the SoapClient error you got.

Answer (score 1):

The composer.lock file stores which versions of packages were installed. When you deploy your application, be sure to include the composer.lock file. Then simply run composer install on the remote machine to make sure the same package versions are installed.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file for more information on composer.lock.